# Sorting multiple arraylists while keeping indexes equal?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

In this java program, i have three arraylists. one is for movie titles, one is for actors, and the last is for the year. I am using collections.sort to allow the user to sort by title, actor, or year. Only problem is that when i sort by titles, the years and actors dont line up correctly to the corresponding title. How can i get the index order from the sorted list(title) and apply that same order to the other two arraylists?
thanks

Comment: Don't do it that way. Create an object with a field for each of title, year and actors, and then have a single list and use three different `Comparator` implementations to sort it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have multiple ArrayLists.

Instead create a "Movie" object which has 3 properties:

1. movie title
2. actor
3. year.

You will need a "getter" method for each property.

Then you add an instance of each "Movie" to a single `ArrayList`.

Then you can sort the `ArrayList` using the `sort(...)` method with a custom `Comparator`.

Something like:

```
movieList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getTitle));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If i already have these arraylists made, i should be able to use them to create the single movielist right? or do i gotta start all over :/

Comment: No you don't start over, it will be about a 5 line code change. Instead of adding the data to the 3 separate ArrayLists, you create your "Movie" object with the 3 pieces of data and then add the "Movie" object so the single ArrayList that is now required. So basically you comment out 3 lines of code and add 2 new lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @camickr sums up your solution, to create on object with those three attributes and customize the terms of comparison.

I just want you to see the reason you had that issue. Each List is determined on it's own collection order. You haven't set any relation between them yet.

Pic below shows what can naturally occur given your current state of 3 separate collections.

[image: The reason you currently have bad results]